# Running next build gives "Error. Could not find a valid built in the '.next' build directory"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

Running `next build` (via `npm run build`) on my remote machine hosting my web app with Next@8.1.0 yields no issues.
Locally I've updated to Next@9.1.3 (in fact, I've been experimenting with various versions to try and fix this issue), running `next build` gives:

```
➜  src git:(master) ✗ npm run build

> @ build /Users/zavide/WebDev/workspace/src
> next build

> Build error occurred
Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/Users/zavide/WebDev/workspace/src/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
    at Server.readBuildId (/Users/zavide/WebDev/workspace/src/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:563:23)
    at new Server (/Users/zavide/WebDev/workspace/src/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:48:29)
    at createServer (/Users/zavide/WebDev/workspace/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:133)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zavide/WebDev/workspace/src/server.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zavide/.npm/_logs/2019-11-09T17_40_34_709Z-debug.log
```

`package.json` looks like this btw:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "next": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
...
```

This has been driving me nuts. How was I able to generate builds before (and still am on my remote machine) and now I suddenly can't? How am I supposed to run `next build` when I can't bloody run `next build` LMAO. Without a build directory, I can't run any production code.

Comment: did you find any solution?